# Edit file on server from a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, vba, server, client-server

What I want to do is to have a set of editable Excel files on my webpage:

- I give links to what for the user represents an Excel file
- With a click, the user's default program for editing Excel files (say, MS Excel) should open
- After finishing editing, the file should be uploaded to my server transparently for the user, and next time the user visits my page, they should see their edited file and be able to edit it again

What I have considered:

- JavaScript Excel-like grid. However, I did not find a JavaScript library with sufficient features, such as easily moving rows (any advice of a good JavaScript Excel component?)
- Saving to DropBox / Google Docs /... using their APIs. However, it requires the user to have an account, and it will probably require me to manage user's DropBox passwords (and not all users will want to share passwords with me). Also, I will need to have interfaces to Google Drive, Miscrosoft OneDrive, and who knows how many other services.
- Allow the user to download the file and rely on the user to upload it back again. However, this is too complicated for the user, and the users will forget to upload the files, which means losing their edits. Any way or uploading the file automatically upon closing?
- A macro in my Excel files that would contact my server before exiting. However, this requires the user to enable macros (security alarm) and may be unreliable if the connection breaks. I did not evaluate whether this is technically possible.

Or what is the best / simplest way to achieve this?

(I know how to generate Excel files and how to open them from the webpage; my problem is how to get the user's edits back to the server transparently for the user.)

Comment: _"Allow the user to download the file and rely on the user to upload it back again. However, this is too complicated for the user, and the users will forget to upload the files, which means losing their edits. Any way or uploading the file automatically upon closing?"_ Why would selecting to save document be "complicated" ? Upload file when user selects to save file ? , or user "closing" which portion of document ?

Comment: "Upload file when user selects to save file?" -- you mean upload it to the server from a VBA script in the Excel file?

Comment: 1) User clicks to open excel editor ; 2) when editing complete user selects to upload edited file at `html` document

Comment: @guest271314 "2) when editing complete user selects to upload edited file at html document" -- would be perfect, but how? can it be done transparently? (My users are not expected to know how to find the downloaded file in Downloads or Temp folder or how to erase temp files from their Downloads folder.)

Comment: _"can it be done transparently? (My users are not expected to know how to find the downloaded file in Downloads or Temp folder or how to erase temp files from their Downloads folder.) "_ ? Not certain interpret "transparently" correctly ? No , cannot programmically select user file from user filesystem. Not sure how user could not be expected to find downloaded ,  edited file at "Downloads" or "Temp" folder , though simultaneously be able , or expected to , edit same excel file ?

Comment: @guest271314 On local computer, the user clicks on an .xls file, Excel opens, the user edits it and closes it -- the edited file is where it was. In my case, the "file" is a link on my page with an Excel icon. The user clicks on it, (chooses "Open" in the browser), Excel opens, he edits the file and closes it -- so he expects the Excel icon on my webpage now to represent the edited file (next time clicking on the icon he expects to see the edits). This would be transparent. Instead, now he should find the edited file where the browser left it, upload it to my server, and remove it locally.

Comment: Is requirement to mirror same file at server , user filesystem ? Similar to git ?

Comment: @guest271314 No, local filesystem has nothing to do. What I want is to have Excel files on the server, editable by the user: the user clicks an icon on the page in the browser, his Excel opens, he edits the contents, closes his Excel, and next time he clicks on the same icon on the same page, he sees edited file. Nothing to do with the local filesystem.

Comment: Excel application launched at server side ?

Comment: @guest271314 No, at client side. That's the problem: some users get used to Office, some to OpenOffice, some to Mac, etc. The idea is for the user to use his own application, but the files should be in the cloud.

Comment: Yes , though how does user upload edited file to server , or "cloud" ?

Comment: @guest271314 That's was my original question :-)) how to ensure transparent (automatic) uploading.

Comment: Possibly to use editor inside of browser ? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/openoffice-writer-on-roll/aefnmlhnadcihhnfplfbmcmodoiannan ? , https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj User should select files from user filesystem ; if file is already in browser , not user filesystem , should be able to mirror file

Comment: @guest271314 Thank you very much! I will play with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this ("get the user's edits back to the server transparently for the user") is to use AJAX (JS) requests to PHP scripts.

AJAX is great for doing things in the background (asynchronously), but it can't edit the server. Just add an event listener in JS (an `onchange` or `onblur`, perhaps) and send an AJAX request every time the user edits the file.

PHP is a great server-side scripting language, and you can edit files with it.

---

**EDIT**: Example (on request)

Assuming that the Excel file is stored in a string in a `<textarea>` for simplicity (for now), you can set a listener to get the data from it (in jQuery), and send an AJAX request:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="excel"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$("#excel").change(function() {
    var excelFile = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "updateFile.php",
        method: "post",
        data: { data: excelFile }
    });
});
```

PHP (updateFile.php):

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $file = fopen("FILENAME.xlsx", "w+");
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please give more details? I know how to use Ajax. If the user uses MS Excel on the client, how will my script know when he has finished edits and how will it get the edited file? If the user edits the file in the browser, then can you advise a good enough JavaScript component, which would allow, say, moving rows?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh I'll give an example right away, don't worry!

Comment: You could write your own JS component, I guess. I don't know any off the top of my head, nor do I know how Excel files work, but if you do, I think you can.

Comment: Yes, I have considered a component, but I can't afford to re-write Google Docs from scratch :-) I've tested http://www.blueshoes.org/en/javascript/spreadsheet/ and http://handsontable.com/examples.html

Comment: Those components look really nice, but you just need to know how to use them and retrieve all of their data into one nice tidy string variable (the `excelFile` JS variable). If you can do this, then the rest of the code can work.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use Ajax to upload the edited string to the server. The only problem is how would the user edit the string.

Comment: The user only has to edit the `<table>`s or `<textarea>`s or whatever input type you have in the HTML. The JS/jQuery would *retrieve* those edited values, which would be sent to the server.

Comment: Yes, I know how to communicate with a component. The only problem then is that I can't find a component that would allow to move rows, order rows, and perhaps more things (and I would prefer not to program it myself).

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh Try [these](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/spreadsheet/). And project-recommendation-requests are kind of off-topic here at SO. I've tried my best to help you from a programming standpoint. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help!